# Change the filepath to save the page content depending on the existence of a page element

Tags: javascript, html, casperjs

I downloaded many pages html with casperjs, but I want separate them in 2 folders. 
some files contains id="trie" and others not.

What can I do, please?

this is my script

```
casper.repeat(j , function(){
  casper.open(arrdata[i]); // arrdata[i] : contains url of file to download
  casper.wait(5000, function(){
    file = 'pages/road/r_' + i +'.html';
    fs.write(file, casper.getHTML(), 'w');
  });
  i++;
});
```

but i want do like this

```
casper.repeat(j, function(){
  casper.open(arrdata[i]);
  if ("id=trie" exists in contains of arrdata[i] ){
    this file is put to pages/trie/...html
  } else {
    this file is put to pages/road/...html
  }
  i++;
});
```

Comment: you mean that the url looks something like this: **http://example.com/somefile?id=trie**  this is a fake url i just asking if that is the format

Comment: or do you mean if there is an element on the page with `id="trie"`?

Comment: have you some ideas? please?

Comment: I mean if there is an element id=trie in page obtained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the exists function:

```
var i = 0;
var fs = require('fs');
casper.repeat(j, function(){
  (function(i){
    casper.thenOpen(arrdata[i], function(){
      if (casper.exists("#Trie")){
        fs.write("pages/trie/"+i+".html", casper.getHTML());
      } else {
        fs.write("pages/road/"+i+".html", casper.getHTML());
      }
    });
  })(i);
  i++;
});
```

Note that this must be done in a step, otherwise you run into concurrency problems. In your code all the `open` calls are executed **before** the first `wait` is executed.

Comment: thank you very much, 
I'll test this and I will keep you posted

Comment: what you mean in a step please? the files are all in pages/road/ ;(

Comment: sorry forgot the IIFE. Are you sure that there are pages which contain `id="trie"`?

Comment: sorry, it's with Trie but not trie, it's my error, but what is ||FE, please?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19324832) shows pretty good what it is and why it is necessary.

Comment: I am debutante on the subject, I do not understand , you can explain to me again?

Comment: ||FE is for having 1,2,3 .... in the folder pages/trie and in the pages/road ? but not 1,4,15 ... in the first and 2,5,... in the second, or I'm wrong?

Comment: I did it already. It is the `(function(i){ /* inner code */ })(i)`. You can look at the [second revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27170523/revisions). It has to be done, because `thenOpen` is asynchronous so the `i` inside will always refer to the last value that `i` is taking. Without the IIFE you would only receive one file in each of the folders. Just try it out and take out the IIFE, but delete every file in those folders. The files will be overwritten `i-1` times.

Comment: I'm sorry , i haven't seen. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I want have a file having noun as 1.html, 2.html , 3.html and so on for each folder, please.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but I'm not here to just give you code. Try it yourself.